# flash dynamic text field

Tags: flash

I want to make auto width text area.  Using xml to pull the data, I would like to expand as data comes in.

```
menu_item_group["menu_item" + i].item_label = nodes[i].attributes.item_label;
```

For example: 
enlarged according to the context menus in this example, the background
http://webscripts.softpedia.com/scriptScreenshots/AS3-XML-MENU---VERTICAL---Screenshots-53313.html

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cooked up a light example for you. The most important part to note is the `myField.autoSize` as that will do what you are looking for. I use `LEFT` by default, but there is also `CENTER` and `RIGHT`. Anyway, in this working example you'll see that the border always fits to the length of the text and that the length is new every time you run the program. Note that this example only works when the `TextField` is set to **Single Line**. Multi Line works differently. ***Good Luck!***

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

var myField:TextField = new TextField();
myField.border = true;

var jibberish:String = "Z";
for(var i=0; i < Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); ++i) jibberish += "Z";

myField.text = jibberish;
myField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

this.addChild(myField);
```